# asdoc "access of undefined property JSON"

Tags: asdoc

I've been doing pages and pages of research and have tried a number of options and now I'm posting to sof in hopes that someone with prior asdoc experience will know how to remedy this:

script:

```
/asdoc  \
-source-path            ./flash/ \
-doc-sources            ./flash/my/packages/ \
-library-path           /Applications/Adobe\ Flash\ CS5/Common/Configuration/ActionScript\ 3.0/libs/ \
                        ./flash/lib/ \
                        ./flash/com/adobe/ \
-exclude-dependencies=true \
-target-player=10.0.0
```

The error I'm getting back is:

```
/project/playlists/JSONItem.as(12): col: 17 Error: Access of undefined property JSON.

            this._json = JSON.decode(this.json);
                         ^
```

The JSON Class is provided by adobe at `com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON`

Thanks!

Comment: FYI I'm using asdocr now from gskinner and I'm still getting the same issue :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I couldn't figure out how to have asdoc compile the additional classes as they were. What I did was downloaded the [swc version of the as3cordlib](http://flex-table.googlecode.com/svn-history/r13/trunk/lib/libs/as3corelib.swc) and dropped that in my ./flash/lib folder and viola. Whenever I run into this, I just generate a swc of the code it's looking for and add it to any folder specified in -library-path.

Also, I started using [asdocr - an asdoc GUI by gskinner](http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2010/05/asdocr_update_f_1.html).

GL all.